# Term Aggregations in Elasticsearch Returning Buckets for Words Instead of Full Field Values

Tags: aggregation, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch query that uses term aggregations:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}                        
    },
    "aggregations" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field": "persona"      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The _source of a sample hit in the result of the query looks like:

```
"_source": {
    "facets": {
        "persona": "research manager",
        "research type": "qualitative"
    },
    "name": "Joe Doe"
}
```

The aggregation buckets look like:

```
"facets": {
    "tag": {
        "_type": "terms",
        "missing": 0,
        "other": 0,
        "terms": [
            {
                "count": 2,
                "term": "research"
            },
            {
                "count": 2,
                "term": "manager"
            }
        ],
        "total": 4
    }
}
```

The term aggregations is considering the words in the persona field instead of the entire value of the field.  Here is the expected output:

```
...
"terms" : [
      {
        "term" : "research manager",
        "count" : 2
      },
      ...
]
....
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I just noticed something odd going on in your Elasticsearch records... persona is within the facets object. Can we see the mapping for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As bittusarkar mentioned, the persona field is most likely getting analyzed.  If you did not specify the mapping or information about that field in the mapping, then it was dynamically added to the mapping by Elasticsearch as type `string` with the default [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).  The analyzer incorporates the standard tokenizer which does a bit more than the whitespace tokenizer but essentially the contents of your field are getting treated as a "bag of words".

Typically, for full text search / Elasticsearch queries you do want the contents to be analyzed so that you can match "research manager" when you search "managers" for example.

One solution would be to use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html).  A snippet of your mapping concerning the persona field might look like:

```
"persona": {
    "type": "multi_field",
    "fields": {
        "persona": { "type": "string" },
        "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
    }
}
```

That way you can do searches like:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "persona" : "Managers"
        }
    }
}
```

And at the same time you can use aggregations:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "aggregations" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field": "persona.raw"      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that instead of `persona`, you are using `persona.raw` for the term aggregations.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the field "persona" is analyzed. Definition of the mapping "sample" should confirm it. `Terms aggregation` works on non-analyzed fields. If the field "persona" is analyzed, it is saved in the index as two different words "research" and "manager". To get what you want, you have to change the field "persona" to non-analyzed. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2) for more information. I'm afraid you cannot make this change in your mapping dynamically. You'll need to re-index all your documents with the updated mapping for the changes to take effect.